# Indent code shortcut in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, indentation

In Eclipse one can indent code by Ctrl+shift+F 
Unfortunately, this does not work in Android Studio.

Is there any opportunity doing this in Android-Studio?

Comment: I think it is Ctrl Alt L or Alt Shift L .

Comment: You can see the shortcut keys in the Prefrences->Keymap menu.

Comment: I didn't see it because I searched for "code indent" not for "code formatting", anyways thank you for your answer refering to this links and for your downvote lol

Comment: First google result with title of your question as keywords ...

Comment: I see, it was my mistake.

Comment: @Blnpwr you should consider more when you accept an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have pretty much two options:

1. Change keymapping from *Settings -> Keymap, and select Eclipse keymap*
2. You can use the default which is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

**EDIT**: people in the comments are suggesting that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>is the correct binding for Linux but the document of IDEA tells you that it's the same with Windows mapping: https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

**EDIT #2**: I sniffed some more info and found this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/412060. So after all you might get in trouble with the default keymapping when using, lets say Ubuntu, so watch out :)

Comment: To add, for Linux users: Ctrl+Alt+L will lock screen on some Linux, so Ctrl+Alt+WinKey+L is default shortcut instead.

Comment: Oh okay, just assumed he/she was using win :)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I am using Linux.

Comment: Thank you for the link, that's a great help for me that is new to Android-Studios. I appreciate this.

Comment: @Blnpwr this should be the accepted answer

Comment: @Charuka done, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

On Mac, <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> will reformat your code for you in your current open file for both your Java files and XML files

On Windows I assume it will be <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: It's not refactor, it's reformat. Refactor means structural changes to code.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly! Thanks @vilpe89

Comment: Does this work on Ubuntu either? I just have seen the comment of Gudin, saying that Ctrl+ALt+L could lock screen on linux, therefore for Linux it is Ctrl+Alt+Win+L, guess. Would be nice if you edit your answer for linux users either. Thank you.

Comment: when we suggest an edit who ignore it and post that suggestion as own one without a single chage don't even deserve that edit

Comment: You took me wrong. I appreciate this answer and marked it as an accepted answer. It is just for the future when someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your file do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> to select all the code and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>  <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd> (default shortcut) to re-indent all the code.